# Regarding switching user in linux environment using libssh

Tags: c++, linux, ssh

I am developing a qt software to update the kernal in the linux system but the linux system is design in such way that i cannot able to login as root directly instead of that i have to login as a normal user and then switch to root. do you guys have any suggestion on how i can proceed with this. I have tried to use ssh_channel_request_exec() function to send the su root

my question is that how should i try to enter the password and establish a interactive terminal session in qt

Comment: This problem is usually completely circumvented by giving your service user some passwordless sudo access, preferably only for specific commands.

Comment: If that is not an option, `ssh_channel_request_pty` is your friend. If `su` sees that it is connected to a PTY you should be able to just send the password over the channel with `ssh_channel_write`.

Comment: Have you tried [sshpass](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass)? But it's much better to use `keypair` with `ssh`